# Why is pandas.read_sas() making random mistakes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, sas

I'm trying to work on a SAS dataset using pandas. The dataset is in `sas7bdat` format, and is encoded in `iso-8859-15`. The dataset is 230,000 rows long and 1300 columns wide.

I'm using the following command to load the data into pandas:

```
pandas.read_sas('my_file.sas7bdat', format='sas7bdat', encoding='iso-8859-15')
```

This works fine for most values, however, some values are read in incorrectly. Values that are read incorrectly often occur along the same row.

For example, say `column 1`'s expected value is `000`, I instead get `0-0`. Then, along the same row, the expected value of another column might be `-000003` but the value in pandas is `00003-0`.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. I've tried searching for this problem everywhere but can't find an answer. I've reloaded the dataset into SAS to see if it's an error with SAS's export, but SAS reads the data in fine.

The changes are still present when I load the dataset directly into raw bytes, which indicates that it's not a problem with the encoding.

Has anyone else come across this problem before? Is there a known issue with [`pandas.read_sas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sas.html) incorrectly reading in data?

Comment: Please set up a [mre] which will be needed for GitHub ticket to pandas team. Since SAS is proprietary, this may involve a downloadable share or binary file-like read in Python.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the input. I will try and create an example tomorrow. I see you're deep in Pandas and SAS, have you ever come across something like this before?

Comment: From the answer below it sounds like the problem is with the compression in the SAS dataset.  Can you get a version of the dataset created with the compression turned off?  That should avoid the issue that the python code is having with uncompressing the rows.

Comment: I have an up to date version of Pandas now too, so I'll definitely give this a try soon!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, except my sas file is encoded latin-1. I also see that some rows of data are fine, and for other rows multiple columns will be incorrect (for example, should be 99999999 but python shows 99962328). As a work around I have used this

```
import sas7bdat
from sas7bdat import *
with SAS7BDAT(file) as reader:
      my_df = reader.to_data_frame()
```

I'm using pandas 1.4.1 so this MIGHT be related to a known bug (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31243); however, I'm seeing the truncation from repeating characters happen at only 21 characters and not 32

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer, but I appreciate the comradery!